# Allow Adventure mode players to click signs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have signs with custom commands linked to them on my Minecraft server, but they can't be clicked in Adventure Mode, is there a way to enable clicking signs in Adventure Mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per default signs are clickable in adventure mode.

Make sure they aren't in the spawn-protected area or anything is blocking their way (like invisible entities or something), because otherwise they won't work.

([spawn-protection wiki entry](http://minecraft-de.gamepedia.com/Server.properties#spawn-protection), non-OP players can't interact with the spawn-protected area, maybe that's the problem).

Comment: That appears to have been the problem! I will edit accordingly. Thank you very much!